# How to select observations of df using datetime index atributes in Pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series, dataframe

Given a df of this kind, where we have DateTime Index:

```
DateTime               A                           
2007-08-07 18:00:00    1
2007-08-08 00:00:00    2
2007-08-08 06:00:00    3
2007-08-08 12:00:00    4
2007-08-08 18:00:00    5
2007-11-02 18:00:00    6
2007-11-03 00:00:00    7
2007-11-03 06:00:00    8
2007-11-03 12:00:00    9
2007-11-03 18:00:00   10
```

I would like to subset observations using the attributes of the index, like:

- First business day of the month
- Last business day of the month
- First Friday of the month 'WOM-1FRI'
- Third Friday of the month 'WOM-3FRI'

I'm specifically interested to know if this can be done using something like:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] < 5) & (df.index == 'WOM-3FRI'), 'Signal'] = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: There is experimental support as of pandas v.0.15.2 for [custom business days](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days-experimental) and associated operations on `DateTimeIndex`

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

```
# FIRST DAY OF MONTH
df.loc[df[1:][df.index.month[:-1]!=df.index.month[1:]].index]

# LAST DAY OF MONTH
df.loc[df[:-1][df.index.month[:-1]!=df.index.month[1:]].index]

# 1st Friday
fr1 = df.groupby(df.index.year*100+df.index.month).apply(lambda x: x[(x.index.week==1)*(x.index.weekday==4)])

# 3rd Friday
fr3 = df.groupby(df.index.year*100+df.index.month).apply(lambda x: x[(x.index.week==3)*(x.index.weekday==4)])
```

If you want to remove extra-levels in the index of `fr1` and `fr3`:

```
fr1.index=fr1.index.droplevel(0)
fr3.index=fr3.index.droplevel(0)
```